# How to create a cron job to run script from web?

Tags: php, cron, centos

I have created a cron job in a server www.domain.com with CENTOS:

```
*/10 * * * * http://www.anotherdomain.com/cron/task.php
```

but its returning:

```
/bin/sh: http://www.anotherdomain.com/cron/task.php: No such file or directory
```

How to make it works?

Comment: either call the remote page with curl or wget

Comment: @Dagon you should put that in an answer as it's the proper solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 */10 * * * *  wget -q -t 5 --delete-after http://www.anotherdomain.com/cron/task.php
```

q = quiet

t = retries incase of network issues (5 in this case)

delete-after = we don't actully want the output of the remote page

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer [curl](http://daniel.haxx.se/) and here are the [reasons you might](http://daniel.haxx.se/docs/curl-vs-wget.html), your cronjob should be:

```
*/10 * * * * curl -s http://www.anotherdomain.com/cron/task.php -o /dev/null
```

s suppresses any status output from curl and -o redirects it to the file following -- in this case, `/dev/null`.