# How to set cron job in cpanel for yii2?

Tags: cron, yii2, cpanel

I want to set `cron` job in cpanel for yii2, I have set the `cron` job but it is not working, My controller name is `Cron`. When I hit the URL, it is working fine.
However, when I set its path in cron it is not working for me, my controller is in frontend/web folder.

Here, I have set its path like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/raanet/public_html/frontend/web/ cron
```

but it is not working for me, can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a cron job to run script from web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389588/how-to-create-a-cron-job-to-run-script-from-web)

Comment: This may / may not help but when my cron job was not working it transpired that I needed to specify the job as php-cli. My final cron statement was: php-cli public/yii controllerName/actionName

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to call a web controller from the console. There are 2 resolutions to this. You can make a console controller, if it is possible in your case. Read about console controllers [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-console-controller). The other thing you can do is, just set up a `curl` request in the crontab instead. Here is a [list](https://www.keycdn.com/support/popular-curl-examples) of examples. Please, let me know how it goes and if there are any other issues.